# How to create an autocomplete search bar with a database in Play!2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, playframework

I assume one would use the autocomplete widget from jquery and set the source to be the database.

How would one go about doing this? How does the widget retrieve data from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) docs and samples and choose the one that you want to use. They demonstrates the required format of data so you just need to build similar in your template with your custom data.